# Why ResponseEntity calls hibernate while lazy loading active

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

Below is the DAO. I am getting the first UppeningUsers object. Note that here for this function I do not want to return peopleWhoBlockedMe set which is located inside the UppeningUsers..

But in different functions I would like to return that information. Note that Both of them are LAZY fetching. With evict I tried to detach the object but still it did not work.

First of all RESTcontroller is below. Then the DAO code is below. Then two entity descriptions are below.

Question is: I see that until

return new ResponseEntity(returned, HttpStatus.OK);

There is only one query which is the typical select. I do not want hibernate to go and take also UserBlock information of that specific UppeningUser. Because it is not needed for this service response. However even though it is lazy loading for some reason
return new ResponseEntity(returned, HttpStatus.OK);
calls the hibernate. I dont know why in restcontroller still it is connected to the database. I tried evict but didnt work.

The json response is
{"id":7,"peopleWhoBlockedMe":[{"blockedId":7}]}

But I do not want for this function to return this peopleWhoBlockedMe. It can be empty.

PLEASE NOTE that in other service for example I will explictly request this peopleWhoBlockedMe but just for this business logic I do not need this information. So what I can do to prevent this so whenever I actually want to call peopleWhoBlockedMe I can get it. Not automaticly.

```
  @RestController

  public class TempController {

@Autowired
UppeningUsersService uppeningUsersService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<UppeningUsers> getPhotos() {
    try {
        UppeningUsers returned = uppeningUsersService.getUsersDetailsPartial();
        return new ResponseEntity<UppeningUsers>(returned, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}


      }
```

This part is the DAO.

```
 @Repository
public class UppeningUsersDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
    this.sessionFactory = sf;
}


/**
 * Get Existing user. Return error if there is not.
 * @param incomingUser user who requested access.
 * @return returns the guy information. All information.
 */
@Transactional
public UppeningUsers getUserDetails() throws Exception {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from UppeningUsers ");

    UppeningUsers returning = (UppeningUsers) query.list().get(0);

    session.evict(returning);

    return returning;

}



 }
```

The main table is this one..

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "uppening_users")
    @Proxy(lazy = true)

    public class UppeningUsers {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private
int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "blockedId",cascade =CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<UserBlocks> peopleWhoBlockedMe;


public UppeningUsers() {
    super();
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

    public Set<UserBlocks> getPeopleWhoBlockedMe() {
    return peopleWhoBlockedMe;
}

public void setPeopleWhoBlockedMe(Set<UserBlocks> peopleWhoBlockedMes) {
    this.peopleWhoBlockedMe = peopleWhoBlockedMes;
}


 }
```

Now here is the other table.

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="user_blocks")
   @Proxy(lazy = true)

  public class UserBlocks {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;

@Column(name = "blocked_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private int blockedId;


public int getBlockedId() {
    return blockedId;
}

public void setBlockedId(int blockedId) {
    this.blockedId = blockedId;
}

}
```

UPDATE: 2 forgot to add the service

```
     @Service("uppeningUserService")
     public class UppeningUsersService {

@Autowired
UppeningUsersDAO uppeningUsersDAO;



public UppeningUsers getUsersDetailsPartial( ) throws Exception {

    return uppeningUsersDAO.getUserDetails();
}








      }
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the Entity classes in the Controller. Read about 3-tier architecture

Comment: then isnt it creating duplicate classes. Why I cant reuse the class which is used in entity.

Comment: Use a Debugger, and look how many informations are stored in an entity, that ahould not be visible for the controller

Comment: So you suggest to create a new business class and set just the ones you want to it and send it ?

Comment: @legend12345, It creates duplicates in the beginning, but then it allows you to fix data format at the presentation layer despite persistence layer's changes. And, btw, your presentation layer's abstraction already differs from your persistence's one, so it is a good time to separate them. Regarding you last commentary - yes, create an additional object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jens is right about her sentence. The layer methodology and writing business objects fix the issue. Thank you.